# Are anti-cheat software (VAC, EasyAntiCheat, BattlEye, etc.) considered as potential threats?

Tags: vulnerability, spyware

Anti-cheat softwares are often flagged by antivirus as malware before they’re manually added to the whitelist, under the assumption that the people behind the anti-cheat act in good intention, and will continue to do so forever. From what I've read online, some of them are essentially keyloggers and/or screenwatchers (among other concerns of low-quality code). Isn’t this like pointing a gun to the user’s head and saying “don’t worry I won’t shoot unless I think you’re a cheater”?

If I bought/subscribed to a game that mandates installation of this software, what should I do (short of buying a separate computer dedicated just to gaming)? Or is this nothing significant to be concerned about, even if sensitive data (private keys for website databases/cryptocurrency wallets) is kept on the same computer?

Comment: Vulnerability means a bug in a software which can be exploitable. I think what you mean by a vulnerability in your subject is threat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of anti-cheat software, is that they try to prevent low level operations that are normally allowed by the system. Essentially, they try to prevent an external application to send mouse events or keystrokes to a game without actual user interaction.

So to prevent that, they have to interact with the system at a very low level, which is exactly the level where keyloggers/mouseloggers should be. That means that the heuristics of an anti-malware have to flag them as suspect.

If you have bought a game requiring to install such a piece of software, my advice is to bring/send it back to the reseller and ask for getting your money back. Unless it was clearly advertised forcing you to use a third party application which is detected as suspect is not acceptable. And including in code operations that are detected as suspect by major anti-virus software is not professional either.

Comment: I think modern anti-cheat software favours detection over prevention, even going so far as to introduce artificial delays to banning. The rationale is that it's much harder to test your cheat code when you get your results a few hours later.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** anti-cheat software (particularly anti-cheat software that runs with elevated privileges) is a *potential* risk to your system.

Any software you install into the kernel should be carefully considered as it increases attack surface.  Typically, gaming software should not have such high privileges.  Even if you trust the source of the software, keep in mind software from respectable companies can still contain exploits...

### Example:  Genshin Impact's mhyprot2.sys Exploit

After your question was posted, there has already been one anticheat that was successfully exploited to achieve privilege escalation.

Per [CVE-2020-36603](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2020-36603/):

> The HoYoVerse (formerly miHoYo) Genshin Impact mhyprot2.sys 1.0.0.0 anti-cheat driver does not adequately restrict unprivileged function calls, allowing local, unprivileged users to execute arbitrary code with SYSTEM privileges on Microsoft Windows systems. The mhyprot2.sys driver must first be installed by a user with administrative privileges.

Anticheat contributing to a system compromise is no longer a hypothetical concern.  In particular here, malicious software that finds its way onto your PC could leverage the faulty anticheat driver to gain unfettered access.

**Risk for players who previously used this driver**

If you've played the game, you may still have the old, buggy version of this driver lying around.  Note that the anticheat driver was initially [not uninstalled on game uninstall](https://www.pcgamesn.com/genshin-impact/anti-cheat).

With this driver in the driver store ([even if not actively installed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/430d18c0-47db-46a5-8c5f-22c604438eee/installing-a-signed-driver-as-nonadmin-user?forum=wdk)), it will be possible for user-mode software to gain admin permissions *without* an admin prompt.

**Risk to the internet in general of this anticheat**

Interestingly, ransomware makers are now [actively using](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/22/h/ransomware-actor-abuses-genshin-impact-anti-cheat-driver-to-kill-antivirus.html) this driver in their malware:

> Such is the case of mhyprot2.sys, a vulnerable anti-cheat driver for the popular role-playing game Genshin Impact. The driver is currently being abused by a ransomware actor to kill antivirus processes and services for mass-deploying ransomware.  Security teams and defenders should note that mhyprot2.sys can be integrated into any malware.

Basically, ransomware makers are now intentionally bundling Genshin's broken anticheat with their malware.  They do this since the drivers are Windows signed, allowing them kernel access to terminate antivirus processes.  That said, people who have not previously played Genshin Impact should see a UAC prompt (assuming the user has not disabled UAC) as the driver would first need to be loaded into the driver store.

A further wrinkle making this attack viable despite the age of the vulnerability (two years!) is that Windows currently has [not been properly blocking old, vulnerable drivers](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/10/how-a-microsoft-blunder-opened-millions-of-pcs-to-potent-malware-attacks/):

> If you thought HVCI was protecting you from recent BYOVD attacks, you were probably wrong. Windows 10 hadn't updated the list in almost three years.

### Recommendations

While the above exploit still requires usermode access, it is not a stretch to imagine that given anticheat's network usage (and poor code quality reputation), an anticheat could one day be found to have a fully remote exploit.  Or, anticheat could be used as one step in a vulnerability chain, leading to a zero-click exploit.  As anticheat becomes more widely used and installed, it will be increasingly tempting to malware creators.

It is up to each person to decide if the increased risk from using anti-cheat is worthwhile, especially if the game still has problems with cheating despite the use of anti-cheat.

**Carefully consider before granting a video game admin permissions:**

For most people, especially ones not interested in hyper-comeptitive shooting games, it's probably best to only play games that can run *fully* in user mode.  Fortunately, this category includes most (modern) games.

Most modern games don't need to request admin privileges anymore, even on first boot.  This used to be necessary in older games for installing DirectX 9 and other redistributables, but recent DirectX versions are [already included in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-directx-d1f5ffa5-dae2-246c-91b1-ee1e973ed8c2).  So be a little bit suspicious of modern game software that requests admin privileges.  They *could* be requesting to install a regular redistributable (like DirectX, etc), but they might also be attempting to install anti-cheat.  Anti-cheat vendors seem to no longer even try to get affirmative user consent before install, and devs have not always listed the use of anti-cheat on store pages.

If a game does request admin mode, you may want to dig into the install scripts a bit to see what it's doing -- or just deny permissions and see what error it gives you.

**Check if anti-cheat is required *before* purchasing:**

Steam has two common places where anti-cheat usage is typically listed.  The first is the right sidebar.  Some games alternatively list use of anticheat in the system requirements at the bottom of the page.  Some games don't list anticheat usage at all, but can be found on [community curated lists](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/List_of_games_with_anti-cheat_technology).

> If I bought/subscribed to a game that mandates installation of this software, what should I do

If the use of privileged software was not clearly indicated as a requirement at the time of sale, this is a valid reason to refund the game.  Furthermore, if the store page does not indicate that anticheat (or other admin privilege software) is used, I recommend leaving a review so others can be aware.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what anti-cheat softwares do, let me tell you what cheats do at first.

**How cheat works:** To achieve cheating, cheats are used methods like code injection into remote process, manipulation of remote process and data, interfacing pointer hooks, hijacking exception handling etc. To kept hidden, cheats often use methods like direct kernel object manipulation (used by rootkits), virtual address descriptor hiding etc. So when you are using cheats you are giving it permission to look and manipulate your memory and other sensitive stuff.

**How Anti-cheat Software works:** What anti-cheat software do is it detects cheats by signature and heuristics (mostly like anti-virus). Sometimes it blocks cheats by detecting obfuscating code or by sandboxing the application. Anti-cheat software like VAC compares MD5 of cheats from VAC's database with the (DLL) files of your hard drive. VAC also check your DNS caches and it’s explicitly searching for entries that correlate with specific cheats. Why does it work? Because The cheat connects to a remote server to see if the user’s license is valid — thus leaving an entry in the DNS cache. [VAC catches that entry, and bans the user.](https://www.extremetech.com/gaming/176829-valve-trust-us-our-vac-anti-cheat-software-isnt-interested-in-your-porn-surfing-habits) Anti-cheat software like [PunkBuster](http://www.evenbalance.com/faq.php#) scan memory to detects the presence of cheats and if it found one, then kicks the player out from the server.

**Is it security risk: Yes it is if it's not from a reliable source.**  So like other software you should be careful about the digital signing, checking md5 etc. Some anti-cheat software installed with the game itself so you do not have to worry if you buy it from the official source and some are installed at servers end so you don't have to install anything hence you are clear. But the sensitive data you have mentioned are should be in a separate secure place where it's highly unlikely to infected by malware of any kind.